# MySql 8.0.24: Dump/Restore fails with nested VIEWS having ROLLUP over DISTINCT groups

Tags: mysql, view, distinct, restore, rollup

## Issue

Assuming following 2 views

```
CREATE VIEW v2 AS SELECT 4711 AS XYZ;
```

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
  SELECT  
    1                   AS A  
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT (1)) AS B
FROM v2
  GROUP BY A WITH ROLLUP;
```

Dumping, restoring the dumped file and calling
`SHOW CREATE VIEW v1;`
leads to following error:

```
FAILS with ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct count(distinct 4711)) AS `B` from `dbfail`.`v2` group by `A` with rollu' at line 1
```

#### In my understanding the dumpfile looks OK. I assume the import/restore can't handle it.

**Of course, above example does not make sence in a business manner. It's reduced to the essence of the problem we are facing!**

## It works fine

- in 8.0.18
- without the ROLLUP modifier
- or without the DISTINCT count
- or when v2 is a TABLE
- OR SURPRISINGLY, and actually the reason for this post ...
  **The failure depends on the names of the views.** More precise, their appearance in the dumpfile!
  If we **switch the names** of the views v1<->v2 its **OK**

## How to repeat

I'm on macOS Catalina with MySql 8.0.24.

Here's a convenient way of testing the fact in a terminal (on mac). (Feel free to pack it in a script)

The first part is the working one and the second fails due to switched view names.

```
SCHEMA=dbok
INNERVIEWNAME=v1
OUTERVIEWNAME=v2
mysql -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $SCHEMA; \
          CREATE DATABASE $SCHEMA; \
          USE $SCHEMA; \
          CREATE VIEW $INNERVIEWNAME AS SELECT 4711 AS anything; \
          CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME AS SELECT 4711 AS A, COUNT(DISTINCT(4711)) AS B FROM $INNERVIEWNAME GROUP BY A WITH ROLLUP; \
          SHOW CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME;"
rm -rf ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysqldump $SCHEMA > ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysql $SCHEMA < ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysql -e "USE $SCHEMA; SHOW CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME;"
```

```
SCHEMA=dbfail
INNERVIEWNAME=v2
OUTERVIEWNAME=v1
mysql -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $SCHEMA; \
          CREATE DATABASE $SCHEMA; \
          USE $SCHEMA; \
          CREATE VIEW $INNERVIEWNAME AS SELECT 4711 AS anything; \
          CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME AS SELECT 4711 AS A, COUNT(DISTINCT(4711)) AS B FROM $INNERVIEWNAME GROUP BY A WITH ROLLUP; \
          SHOW CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME;"
rm -rf ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysqldump $SCHEMA > ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysql $SCHEMA < ./$SCHEMA.mysql
mysql -e "USE $SCHEMA; SHOW CREATE VIEW $OUTERVIEWNAME;"
```

## How can I overcome this problem?

Except for the renaming, of course!. Is anybody else facing this problem too? Is there a proper solution (e.g. dump restore params)? I could not find any comment on this issue yet ...

Comment: if you can repeat it make a bug report

Comment: following your advice, thanks!
[link](http://bugs.mysql.com/103583) to MySql BugReport

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8.0.23, the mysqldump looks like below, and i cannot see a correct `CREATE VIEW` statement in it.

Maybe you have found a bug, and should report it to: https://bugs.mysql.com/ ?

EDIT: oops, I always thought that where (a lot of) comments, but: [WHOA! These aren't really comments even though they look that way. They are conditional-execution tokens.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1917437/724039)

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.23, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.23

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Temporary view structure for view `v1`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `v1`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v1`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW `v1` AS SELECT 
 1 AS `A`,
 1 AS `B`*/;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;

--
-- Final view structure for view `v1`
--

/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `v1`*/;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_client          = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_cs_results         = @@character_set_results */;
/*!50001 SET @saved_col_connection     = @@collation_connection */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = cp850 */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = cp850 */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = cp850_general_ci */;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`luuk`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `v1` AS select rollup_group_item(1,0) AS `A`,rollup_sum_switcher(distinct count(distinct 1)) AS `B` from `v2` group by `A` with rollup */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_client      = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!50001 SET character_set_results     = @saved_cs_results */;
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = @saved_col_connection */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2021-05-04 19:37:14
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed in 8.0.26. See [MySQL Bug #103583](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103583)

Comment: tested: indeed, above scenario works on a MySQL 8.0.26 installation on macOS Catalina (10.15.7).